# In app purchase flutter, upgrade subscription plan

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

to upgrade a subscription plan we need to pass the old purchase details ,how do we get the old purchase details using in app purchase in flutter

I am unable to get the old purchase details to be sent to google pay to upgrade plan

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.